# What unit types can enter bunkers in SC2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I know that in melee, SCVs, marines, marauders, ghosts and reapers can enter a bunker (and I assume so can medics, firebats and spectres in the single-player). Can any other unit types enter a bunker? In particular, **can any non-Terran unit enter it**? (assuming it somehow got under your control in the first place)

And if any other unit can enter a bunker, how much space does it take? Same as with transports?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any Terran Infantry unit can enter a bunker. Bunkers are restricted to Terran units exclusively, so you'll have to find another secret place if you want to cuddle zerglings in private.

[image: pic incoming]

None of the units in the above picture could join the bunker party.

Comment: You haven't tried broodlings! :)

Comment: Or interceptors!

Comment: What about infested terran?

Comment: Even landed Vikings?

Comment: Infested Terrans would be an interesting edge case.  I mean, they have "Terran" right there in their name!

Comment: @BlueRaja isn't that an infested terran behind the hydra?

Comment: @Oak -- that's a changeling, dressed like a marine.

Comment: Dogs and infested terran must stay outside!

Comment: awww, poor units can't join the party :(