# Are there any games/tactics where infestor controlled units are used to build "foreign" units?

Tags: starcraft-2

I recently completed the "[Zerglot](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Zerglot#Melee_Combat)" achievement, as described [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=140850).

In short, you have to warp in a Zealot, while playing Zerg. You can do this, by using neural parasite (Infestor) on an enemy probe and use the probe to build a nexus. Then you control a nexus and you can start up your own Protoss build and go for Gateway and then Zealot.

While something like this is most likely extremely difficult to pull off against a human opponent, I was wondering if this has actually been used in game before? Are there any games where somebody uses this to produce a Zerg/Protoss or Zerg/Terran unit mix on his own?

If there's no game you know of, what do you think of this strategy in general?
I guess it could be doable in the case where your opponent has a weakly defended expansion up and you can capture one of his workers?

In case of a Protoss opponent you would "only" need to:

- control a probe for a short amount of time to warp in a nexus
- protect the nexus until completion, build a probe
- go anywhere with *your* probe to build a protected nexus/structures (build an expansion)

Comment: Would you be interested in opening up this question from just "previous executions of this tactic" to asking if it is an effective tactic, and if it has been successfully (or unsuccessfully) used in the past? The question is fine as is, but I think the expansion may eke out some more detailed answers.

Comment: @Grace Note: Done. Expanded a bit on the question. Playing vs. Protoss is probably the most realistic case.

Comment: I just wanted to mention this because I didn't see it brought up. If you NP a terran SCV, when it wears off, the SCV will stop building the building and you will need to NP it again and tell the SCV to continue building. Which is probably why the achievement is to capture a probe instead because once you start warping, the probe can die off and you'll still have a nexus.  I also can't remember if you end up sharing supply with the new protoss units or if they count are a new set (like in SC1).

Comment: Here's another way to get the Zerglot achievement: Play a ladder 2v2 game where you play Zerg, and your teammate is Protoss. Your teammate leaves, you warp in a zealot with his warp gate. This is actually the easiest way to earn this achievement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did see one game commentated by Husky where a Zerg player captured an SCV which was sent to repair a tank on the battlefield, and he did work up the Terran tech tree. But I think that game was really just for fun as many bizarre things happened, and the players goofed around more than actually playing to win (maybe someone remembers that one and can give a link?). I have never seen anywhere else where neural parasite was used like this in a legitimate game.

I would say this is not feasible in a legitimate game because:

1. The amount of infestor energy required to pull this off would be probably be better spent elsewhere. You need to escort the worker via parasite back to your base, then throughout construction of the building. OTOH, parasiting a probe is easiest because a Nexus warps in instantly.
2. It will take a long time to get to a point where this is even possible. By this time, you won't benefit much from the other race's low-tier units & structures. If it were hypothetically possible in the early game, I could see a benefit to using terran supply depots for a wall-off, or getting quick marines for anti-air.
3. The APM required to efficiently use this tactic again would probably be better spent elsewhere. This is not a tactic you will ever bother practicing, so if you actually do this, you will be basically treading in unknown waters throwing off your natural rhythm. How will you hotkey your new command center or barracks for example?
4. If your creep spreading is what it should be, then your options are limited for building placement. As Terran at least you could head to an island as a workaround.

There are lots of low-tier "foreign" abilities that could possibly be practical though, if you get really lucky and manage to pull this off:

2. Chrono boost on Zerg upgrades or larva
3. Marine + roach or muta army composition
4. Scanner sweep / MULEs
5. Missile turrets
6. Planetary fortresses
7. Bunkers for roaches / hydras

Though most of these are still not going to be practical if you have any creep spreading.

In 2v2 I have always wondered though if allys have used this tactic. It would be MUCH more feasible here because:

1. You could build your 2nd race base amongst your ally, avoiding creep
2. You don't need to bother keeping a hold of the worker with neural parasite as much. If your ally is Protoss, it would just take 1 neural parasite.
3. Creep spread tends to be more conservative in team games unless your ally is also Zerg.

But in a team game of course it's also less compelling because you already get the army composition. The biggest benefit would be chrono boost, or sharing transports. I won't mention "less communication required between teammates" because well, you should just aim to improve the communication, not work around it :)

But I have never heard even a mention of doing this amongst allys in a team game; maybe you cannot neural parasite an ally?

Comment: no, you cannot parasite ally's unit

Comment: [Only Terran infantry can enter bunkers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/what-unit-types-can-enter-bunkers-in-sc2/14039#14039), so the bunker tactic won't work at all.

Comment: Also, can non-Protoss buildings be chrono boosted? Regardless, fun ideas!

Comment: I read a thread somewhere that questioned whether you could NP an anny mothership so he could build another one and end up with 2. In the same line of thinking, you could NP high-supply-count units and allow your non-Zerg ally to get over 200 supply (Zerg can already do it by making cheap buildings and canceling them).

Answer (score 4):

Destiny used an Infestor to build a Nexus in a ZvP (Grandmaster ladder game). There's a [replay](http://www.sctemple.com/replay/221591/) and a [VOD](http://www.own3d.tv/Destiny#/watch/547045) available, in the video the match starts at around `01:11:00`, Infestor-Probe-capturing at around `01:29:00` where the Protoss throws away probes to free up supply.

While the APM is mostly used elsewhere, the Zerg player still manages to tech up to a mothership and using chrono-boost to speed up upgrades (both protoss- and zerg upgrades).

This does show that while this is still gimmicky and extremely hard to pull off, it can be quite beneficial to the Zerg player. Since you cannot be sure to capture a probe in every game, it would be foolish to build on such a strategy. Although it might be another reason to research neural parasite in the later stages of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Actually yea,

I found this post because I wanted to see if ANY games like this were played before and I cant seem to have found one.

A replay of my brother 2 days ago where he controlled Zerg and Protoss against a human opponent.

[replay ZvP going on ZPvP](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=RS2TNNK1)